# What would be a good randomization environment for data science?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, numpy, scipy

I would like to know if there are any best practices to optimize random environment. Currently I use this simple structure in my config :

```py
from numpy.random import Generator, PCG64
rng = Generator(PCG64(42))
np.random.seed(42)
```

I use the `rng` generator for all general purposes (draw following a certain distribution, permutation of index, synthetic datapoints, etc.) and use the legacy `np.random.seed` to set the random state of scipy for the `rvs` method of `scipy.stats` generators.

I read somewhere in the sklearn doc (warning section [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#randomized-parameter-optimization)) that the `sklearn.model_selection` module uses the same global seed, that would the global seed set with `np.random.seed` isn't it ?

If you have a better understanding of how scipy and sklearn refers to the global seed and what would be a good default randomization setup, it would be very usefull. Thanks